# While submitting flink job through savepoint it's throwing java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied) in windows server 2012

Tags: apache-flink

I have given full access to the savepoint folder then also it's getting access denied exception, but in Linux it's working as expected.

Comment: can you provide a stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Flink savepoint command is expecting full path of the file including Filename.
So i have changed accordingly ,now it's working in both windows and linux.